# I can't change the TextView text from a thread

Tags: android, multithreading, settext

I'm trying to change a textView from my thread, but it always crashes. Why?

```
public void startProgress(View view) {

    bar.setProgress(0);
    new Thread(new Task()).start();
}

class Task implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
            final int value = i;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            bar.setProgress(value);
            text.setText("i = "+i);
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know why i can't change it. Anyone knows why?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot modify the activity's or fragment's UI from a background thread, except in a few select circumstances (e.g., `ProgressBar`).

Answer (score 0):

Views can only be modified by their parent thread. This is a common problem that people face, unfortunately you just have to work around it.

Answer (score 0):

Use runOnUiThread

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
           final int value = i;
           try {
              Thread.sleep(1000);
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
          bar.setProgress(value);
          text.setText("i = "+i);
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: When I use runOnUiThread it works, but it just update the content when it finishes the loop. After activate "startProgress" I can't touch the UI for 10 seconds (The time that lasts the loop), then appears the text changed with i=10, but during the process UI is bloked.

Answer (score 0):

As @dodo or @CommonsWare said you must access View hiearhcy in the main ui thread.
To comply with this rule, use *Handler.post(Context.getMainLooper())*

```
new Handler(context.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        bar.setProgress(value);
        text.setText("i = "+i);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I fixed it. Thanks anyway.

```
public void startProgress(View view) {

    bar.setProgress(0);
    //new Thread(new Task()).start();

    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i=0; i<10;i++){           
                final int timer = i;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        text.setText("velocitat: "+timer);
                    }
                });
                bar.setProgress(timer);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    th.start();
}
```